# Where to find older version of REST API plugin for openfire version 3.9 (XMPP Chat)

Tags: rest, plugins, xmpp, openfire

How to install `rest api` on `open-fire` server version 3.9?

we have a pre implemented application on `open-fire 3.9`. Now we want to update the functionality with `rest api`. But `rest api` required `open-fire version 4.0+`.

So how is it possible?
if any one have an alternate then please help me.

Comment: Its too difficult to understand your question. Can you re-phrase your question with better English? What exactly do you want to achieve with rest api that you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

You need an older version of the plugin, hoping it supports what you need.

You can download by following this link:
https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/56342